# Visual Studio Code, SFDXError with retrieve for Aura and LWC

Tags: vs-code, sfdx-plugin, visualstudiocode

since yesterday I started having an issue when I try to use the command SFDX:retrieve source from Org on Aura or LWC items. The command fails and I receive this error message:

[image]

Also, I noticed that If I create a new Project (SFDX:create project with manifest), my folder structure for Aura and LWC is somehow messed up:

[image]

Comment: Try updating your SFDX (from command line: `sfdx update`) and try again

Comment: thanks but it seems the same error persists :( I had also some issues with JAVA_HOME not pointing to the correct path, but I fixed it without being able to solve this present issue still. Maybe I should disinstall VS code and reinstall it again with all the extensions